# Would you, please, help to linearize this system state equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-control

State equation:
$$\dot{x}_1 = x_2$$
$$\dot{x}_2 = -\frac{k}{M}\exp(-x_1)x_1-\frac{h}{M}x_2+\frac{1}{M}u$$

Output equation:
$$y= x_1$$
Would you, please, help to linearize this system state equations?

Comment: Did you notice the lack of response? You'll have to add a lot of context if you want a reasonable answer: who's $u$, and what about $y$? Linearization is always local, you replace a surface by a tangent hyperplane, but in which point exactly is that the tangent? You could tell us where are the interesting regions of your model, or just explain the model, maybe we can identify the interesting regions.

Comment: y is output, u is input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to linearize a system of the form 
$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{u})$$
$$\boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{h}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{u})$$

at the reference state $\boldsymbol{x}_R$ and the reference input $\boldsymbol{u}_R$ you need to evaluate the following expressions
$$\Delta\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{f}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}\bigg|_{\boldsymbol{x}_R,\boldsymbol{u}_R} \Delta\boldsymbol{x}+\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{f}}{\partial\boldsymbol{u}}\bigg|_{\boldsymbol{x}_R,\boldsymbol{u}_R} \Delta\boldsymbol{u}$$
$$\Delta\boldsymbol{y}=\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{h}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}\bigg|_{\boldsymbol{x}_R,\boldsymbol{u}_R} \Delta\boldsymbol{x}+\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{h}}{\partial\boldsymbol{u}}\bigg|_{\boldsymbol{x}_R,\boldsymbol{u}_R} \Delta\boldsymbol{u}.$$

The following abbreviations were used $\Delta \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x}_R$ and $\Delta \boldsymbol{u}=\boldsymbol{u}-\boldsymbol{u}_R$.

The gradients

$$\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{f}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}},\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{f}}{\partial\boldsymbol{u}}, \dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{h}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}} \text{ and } \dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{h}}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}    $$

are all evaluated at ${\boldsymbol{x}_R,\boldsymbol{u}_R}$.

For your case, this is very easy. Your first state equation is already linear so is your output equation. You only need to linearize the second state equation. We obtain:

$$\Delta \dot{x}_1=\Delta x_2$$
$$\Delta \dot{x}_2 = -\frac{k}{M}\left[-\exp(-x_1)x_1+\exp(-x_1)\right]\bigg|_{x_{R1}}\Delta x_1-\frac hM \Delta x_2 + \frac{1}{M}\Delta u$$

$$\Delta y = \Delta x_1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\array{\dot{z_1} \\ \dot{z_2}}\right)=\left[\array{0 & 1\\ 
\frac{-k}{M}e^{-x_1}(1-x_1) & \frac{-h}{M}}\right]
\left(\array{z_1 \\ z_2}\right)
+\left(\array{0\\ \frac{u}{M}}\right)$$

$$y=(\array{1 & 0})\left(\array{z_1 \\ z_2}\right)+\left(\array{x_1 \\ 0}\right)$$

I have used z variables instead of x variables to state the linearized equation in terms of the basis vectors of the linear space (the tangent space) at $x$.  Looking at the answer should tell you how we get to that answer.  If something is not clear, you can leave me a message in the comments and I'll reply.